# Conceptually, how do commutation relations result in quantized fields in QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

I was reading [this explanation](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node42.html#:%7E:text=form%20a%20right%20handed%20orthogonal,(density%20integrated%20over%20volume).) of how the EM field can be quantized, where they show that the expression for the Hamiltonian of the EM field, in terms of the ladder operators, results in a commutation relationship between the ladder operators that's the same as in the case of the 1D harmonic oscillator.  Then they say

> This means everything we know about the raising and lowering operators applies here. Energies are in steps of $\hbar\omega$ and there must be a ground state.

and that's where I get confused.

I can follow the derivation, in Griffiths' QM text, of the recursive formula for the energies of the quantum harmonic oscillator and it made intuitive sense that they increase in steps of $\hbar\omega$, because that derivation started with a wavefunction derived from solving the Schrödinger equation with appropriate boundary conditions, and I understand how boundary conditions can cause quantization of wavefunctions, similarly (but not exactly the same) as the quantization of standing waves in classical wave mechanics.

But in the linked derivation, there are no wavefunctions that I see, and no differential equations with boundary conditions being applied.  Instead, the implication is that the commutation relation between the ladder operators is the cause of the quantization and I don't understand why this would be the case. Conceptually, what do commutation relations specifically (as opposed to any of the other mathematical tools used in QM) have to do with why fields are quantized?  That just seem so *different* from the explanation of why wavefunctions in QM are quantized (boundary conditions applied to wavefunctions), that I'm struggling to see how they can be related.

Comment: wavefunctions in QM are quantized?

Comment: Wave functions are not quantized because of boundary conditions, to begin with. Boundary conditions are, at most, establishing a discrete spectrum, which is often mistaken for "quantization". The "essence" of quantum mechanics is the requirement that physical interaction only takes place through quanta of energy with non-zero angular momentum, which is expressed in the non-commutativity of the P, Q algebra. The quantum harmonic oscillator is likely the most simple non-trivial system that has that property.

Comment: @flattermann, isn't a "quanta" of energy, by definition, a discrete quantity though?  If not, what does the term mean in this context?

Comment: @tobiasfunke, That's certainly what I've been taught -- e.g. the discrete/quantized energy levels of an electron in an atom arise due to the boundary conditions applied to the Schrödinger equation.  I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to get at by suggesting they aren't quantized.  

Comment: Quanta are quanta of energy, but that "a measurement returns a quantum of energy" is a trivial consequence of the irreversible character of measurement. What else can a single measurement return than one number? That is even so in classical mechanics. That a quantum measurement changes the system's angular momentum by one Planck unit, however, that is a non-trivial physical difference compared to classical mechanics.

Comment: I don't understand this question: It sounds as if you think commutation relations are somehow something specific to QFT, but the canonical commutation relation $[x,p] = \mathrm{i}\hbar$ is central to ordinary QM, too! What do you mean when you say "wavefunctions are quantized" or "fields are quantized"? In standard terminology, it is the *theory* that is quantized, or (if you actually mean "discretized") the *spectra* of the observables.

Comment: @ACuriousMind But not even the spectra are quantized. Neither energy, momentum or location are quantized for free particles. As mentioned... discretization is not the same as quantization. Experimentally the only properties that are truly quantized are angular momentum and the charges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the quantization of field and the quantization of energy or momentum.

When you consider the bound state problem of QM, a boundary condition quantize the energy. This is one thing that is true, and all the same thing happens in QFT, for example, when you consider the quantum photons between two conductors (it is well-known as the Casimir effect). But in this case, what is discretized is the energy which appears on the exponential, not the quantized field itself.
Let us write this more explicitly.

If we consider the photon without boundary, we will obtain following mode expansion:
$$A^\mu(x)=\sum_\lambda \int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\Big(\epsilon^\mu_\lambda\ a(p,\lambda)\ e^{ikx}+h.c.\Big).$$
In this case, $k$ takes continuum value because we don’t impose any boundary conditions. In QM point of view, this correspond to consider the scattering problem of waves. We here note that $\epsilon^\mu_\lambda e^{ikx}$ on the right hand side is wave function of photon. So even in QFT wave functions are appeared through the mode decomposition. More intuitive discussion will find in [Schwartz](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/).

On the other hand, if we consider the photon with boundary, a mode expansion is modified to the discretized one. Therefore energy or momentum take the discretized value, and the four-dimensional integral above become a combination of a continuum integral and discretized summation: e.g. $\sum_n\int\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}$, where $n$ is a energy index. In this case, of course the wave function that will appear in the mode decomposition is discretized. But this is not a quantization of fields.

This is a quantization of energy or momentum.

**The important point is the quantization of field is completely different from that of energy or momentum.**

What we have to do to quantize the field is to impose the commutation relation to the field:
$$[A^\mu(x), \Pi^\nu(y)]_{\mathrm{Equal}\ \mathrm{Time}}=g^{\mu\nu}\delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf y),$$
where $\Pi$ is a conjugate momentum of $A$.
This is a quantization of field. **We don’t need any boundary condition to quantize the field.**

From this quantization condition, we can derive the Hamiltonian and commutation relations between the creation/annihilation operators of $A^\mu$,
$$[a(\mathbf p,\lambda),\ a^\dagger(\mathbf p’,\lambda’)]=\delta_{\lambda, \lambda’}\delta^3(\mathbf p-\mathbf p’),$$
$$H=\sum_\lambda\int\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} a^\dagger(\mathbf k,\lambda) a(\mathbf k,\lambda). $$
This is why quantum (free) fields are harmonic oscillators of infinite dimension. More detailed explanation is found e.g. [Srednicki](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) or other QFT books.

Anyway,

1. The quantization of field and the quantization of energy or momentum are different concept.
2. Field quantization lends a canonical commutation relation to field operators and their conjugate momenta. In this case, no boundary conditions are necessary. **Especially, a field quantization does not discretize an energy or momentum.**
3. Quantization of energy or momenta is closely related to the boundary condition of space-time. If we are interested in the system with boundary condition (e.g. the Casimir effect), some of 4-momentum are discretized. But this is independent of the quantization about fields.

Comment: Is field quantization observable ?  All particles are excitations of the field .... so particles are the observables of field quantization?

Comment: I don’t understand how this fact relates to my answer, but I give a short comment. Because of gauge symmetry of our world, the creation/annihilation operator of electrons, photons and etc.  are not observable simply because they are not gauge invariant. If they are observable, a conservation of current would be broken. We can consider them, but we cannot observe themselves.

Comment: Oh, OK, you are not satisfied the terminology of “wave function of photons” because we can’t define the one photon state, two photon state, etc. with keeping a gauge invariance. That’s true. My answer was naive extension of the discussion for a free scalar field, but it was too naive. Yes, we should be careful to that point.

Comment: I am not an expert on QFT .... I was just asking to learn more about field quantization compared to QM quantization.  In QM we see the energy levels of the hydrogen spectrum ..... but in QFT can we see evidence of the quantizations of the field?

Comment: OK. I strongly recommend you to ask another question, not using comment. But I give a last short comment. QFT is simply the application of the experimentally established axioms of quantum mechanics to a field which has infinite degrees of freedom. This is a coarse assertion that should not be given undue credence, but QFT is simply a reorganization of the many-body problem of quantum mechanics into an easier-to-handle form, and the verification of quantum mechanics is completely equivalent to the verification of quantum field theory.

Comment: Also,  you should note that quantized/discretized energy spectrum is not necessary condition or sufficient condition for quantum theory. If you consider the scattering problem in QM, you don’t have any discrete value. If the system does not have a specific boundary conditions, field quantization does not introduce any quantized/discrete value like discretized energy spectrum.